# ListPlot of imaginary part

Tags: plotting

Assuming I have a list like:

```
{{1, 1. - 0.0169212 I}, {2, 0.99611 + 0.0326189 I},
 {3,1.02048 + 0.0945609 I}, {4, 1.02722 + 0.138977 I}}
```

When I try now

```
ListPlot[Im[List]]
```

I got points only on $x=0$, since the imaginary part of all the "$x$-points" is zero. How can I plot what is really meant by the command above? So that only the second entry of the tuple get's the `Im`.

Comment: 2 things: 1) Call your list `list`, not `List` 2) since your x-coords are `1,2,3,4...`,  `list[[All, 2]] // Im // ListPlot` will work - otherwise use @AlexeiBoulbitch 's solution

Comment: Take a look at `MapAt`.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
ListPlot[lst /. {x_, y_} -> {x, Im[y]}]
```

returning this:

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

**Data:**

```
{{1, 1. - 0.0169212 I}, {2, 0.99611 + 0.0326189 I}, {3, 1.02048 + 0.0945609 I}, {4, 1.02722 + 0.138977 I}};
```

**Operation:**

```
ListPlot[Im[%[[All, 2]]]]
```

**Output:**

[image: Output visual representation]

**Reference:**

[ListPlot](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html?q=ListPlot)
[%](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616)
[[[]]](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
w={{1, 1. - 0.0169212 I}, {2, 0.99611 + 0.0326189 I},{3,1.02048 + 0.0945609 
  I}, {4, 1.02722 + 0.138977 I}};
f[w_] := w /. {a_, b_} :> {a, Im[b]};
list = f@w
ListPlot[list]
```